# Indentation in Python error

Tags: python

Im new to python and trying to create a tictactoe game to learn the syntax and keep running into issues with indentation. My understanding is that as long as the whitespace is consistent then the program should run? Here is the code:

```
board = [ 
            ['|', '|', '|' ],
            ['|', '|', '|'],
            ['|', '|', '|'] 
        ] 

player1 = ''
player2 = ''


def tictactoe ():

    player1 = raw_input('What is player one name?')
    print(player1)
    player2 = raw_input('What is player two name?')
    print(player2)



def getMove ():
# get move and pass it to testMove

def getMove ():
# get move and pass it to testMove

# def testMove():
# test for moves and pass to make move

# def makeMove ():
#make move and loop back to getMove
```

Im doing this in sublime. Any ideas as to why im getting this error:

```
"  File "test.py", line 27

    ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
"
```

Comment: Please read the Python style guide, [PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). Indentation should be 4 spaces, and tabs should be avoided, since different editors treat them in different ways (Sublime, for example, allows you to specify how many spaces a tab takes up), whereas the Python interpreter sees them as 8 spaces. To avoid confusion and pointless errors, *please* just use 4 spaces. It looks nice, is readable, and consistent with how pretty much everyone else does it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify contents in your functions or use `pass` to leave them unimplemented:

```
def getMove ():
    pass
```

Comment: Thanks. Any way to have syntax hint or error checking? Any packages in sublime or iPython?

Comment: Not that I know of. Part of becoming a good programmer is being able to debug and understand error codes. An error like this is a good indication to look before the line, in the line, and after the line for any errors in your code.

Comment: And if this was of any use to you, please mark as answer with the check beside my answer.

Answer (score 5):

If this is your full code, you can't do this:

```
def getMove ():
# get move and pass it to testMove

# def testMove():
# test for moves and pass to make move
```

The functions should have some content. You can create empty functions, but at least one line should be written, for example:

```
def getMove():
#get move and pass it to testMove
    pass
```

### EDIT

As stated by @SethMMorton , you can also do this without using `pass`, and keeping the same structure of your code, just changing

```
def getMove():
#get move and pass it to testMove
    pass
```

for

```
def getMove():
    """Get move and pass it to testMove"""
```

These are called docstrings, and are used to describe not only how to use functions but also to describre other things, like classes content and attributes. This way, you would get no identation error as well.

Comment: Or, if the comment was replaced with a [docstring](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/) at the correct indentation level, it would work without the `pass`.  I would advocate that the OP do this instead, since dostrings should be used for describing how to use a function and it's intent instead of comments.

Comment: @SethMMorton Very well observed! I will add that to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your function definition should have at least one code statement. Please note that you also defining getMove() twice and you should remove one of them.

```
board = [ 
        ['|', '|', '|' ],
        ['|', '|', '|'],
        ['|', '|', '|'] 
    ] 

player1 = ''
player2 = ''


def tictactoe ():

   player1 = raw_input('What is player one name?')
   print(player1)
   player2 = raw_input('What is player two name?')
   print(player2)



def getMove ():
   pass
```

Answer (score 0):

Python expects a function definition after `def getMove():`. As the error says, it expected an indented block, namely your function definition. If you don't want to define a function yet, you can use the `pass` statement, which is used when you need a statement for syntactical reasons, but you don't want to do anything (yet).

```
def getMove():
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

Not to forget to implement the function, raise NotImplementedError.

```
def getMove():
    """get move and pass it to testMove"""
    raise NotImplementedError
```